# how to bind empty pojo in jsp page using model attribute and spring form tags

Tags: spring

if anyone knows spring please help me:

I have a registration form in which user fill personal details then it click next button 
then another registration page displayed for qualification ..i am using model attribute and spring form tags for saving user conversational state or for populating pojos...but i am facing problem in binding the model attribute in jsp page in the second method "qualification pattern " we get the populated candidate pojo and i am trying to bind empty qualification in RegQualification page but this is not working..below is the controller.......

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public class RegisterController {

          //Displaying reg page
        @RequestMapping("/regCandidate")
        public String regCandidate(Candidate can)
        {
            return "RegCandidate";
        }


         //saving candidate and displaying reg qualification page
        @RequestMapping(value="/qualification" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String regCandidate(Candidate can, HttpSession hs, Qualification q)
        {
            hs.setAttribute("candidate_personal", can);
            return "RegQualification";
        }

    //saving qualification and displaying reg project page
        @RequestMapping(value="/project" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String regQualification(Qualification q,HttpSession hs,Project p)
        {
            hs.setAttribute("candidate_qualification", q);
            return "RegProject";
        }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but from what I interpret you should be looking to use model.addAttribute() rather than HttpSession.setAttribute

Comment: I have divided the registration details in 3 pages namely personal, qualification and project. The pojo-population from personal page to qualification page is working correctly but the qualification-pojo-population from qualification page to project page is not working. This is the problem.

Comment: Well as said previously the Spring way is to use a Model and addAttribute() to pass values between a Bean and a jsp, not sure I can help you otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/qualification" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView regCandidate(Candidate can, HttpSession hs, Qualification q)
    {
        return new ModelAndView("RegQualification","candidate_personal",can);
    }
```

then in RegQualification.jsp you can access the object 'can' like this :

```
<p> Candidate's name is ${candidate_personal.name} </p>
```